# How can I restore the VirtualBox graphical user interface to show the snapshot menu?

Tags: virtualbox

My VirtualBox GUI is missing the snapshot menu. How can I restore the menu bar that features this entry?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Right click in the bottom margin of the window and select "Show Toolbar"